# ubuntu 14.04 wired connection connects and disconnects

Tags: linux, ubuntu, broadcom

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on a HP Proliant dl380 gen 9 two weeks ago. Ever since I installed, it has been misbehaving by automatically disconnecting during the day and connecting again at night and during week ends (Disconnecting during peak hours). If I unplug and plug the network cable during the day, it tends to connect for some minutes and then disconnects (while showing the connected icon on the network area). The output of the command `lspci -knn | grep Eth -A2` returns

`02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM5719 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [14e4:1657] (rev 01)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:22be]
Kernel driver in use: tg3`

`02:00.1 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM5719 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [14e4:1657] (rev 01)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:22be]
Kernel driver in use: tg3`

`02:00.2 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM5719 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [14e4:1657] (rev 01)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:22be]
Kernel driver in use: tg3`

`02:00.3 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM5719 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [14e4:1657] (rev 01)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:22be]
Kernel driver in use: tg3`

Comment: Power saving options somewhere? Had a similar issue on Jessie driving me nuts. Don't quite remember what I did to solve, but had it fixed eventually. Also, having any more than one tool to manage the network and device/s may cause trouble.

Answer (score 0):

At last was able to find the answer through [14e4:1687 broadcom tg3 network driver disconnects under high load](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1447664). Disabling highdma with ethtool seems to work around the issue, to make the solution permanent add udev rule in /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="net", ATTRS{vendor}=="0x14e4", ATTRS{device}=="0x1687", RUN+="/sbin/ethtool -K %k highdma off"
```